# Challenge: Find the unique value in an array of even or odds numbers

Tags: algorithm, search, comparison, logic

You have an array of numbers in which most of the elements except one will be different, example:

- All the elements can be even and you have to find the position of the odd element.
- All the elements can be odd and you have to find the position of the even element.

here is the best solution that came to my mind:

```
let numbers = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,17,18,20];
let matchingValue = ((numbers[0] % 2) === (numbers[1] % 2)) ?
                        (numbers[0] % 2) : (numbers[2] % 2);

for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  if((numbers[i] % 2) !== matchingValue) {
     console.log(i);
  }
}
```

I'm curious to see if we can find a better solution or if this is the best so far (which I don't think it's)

**Also I refer to optimize in a logical level**, so it doesn't matter if the name of a variable is too long for example as long as the logic is robust and the final algorithm will result in a more performant one.

You can also use any programming language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664127/7879193 What do you want to optimize? Are you looking for O(1) or O(1/n) algorithm?!

Comment: I'm not looking for a specific algorithm, I'm looking for the best we can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I try with C # and this makes me the same function as your code, the algorithm recognizes negative numbers (I do not know if you have it as a condition).
Also, I recognize that this code can also be optimized. [Try here](https://repl.it/MO5q/1)

```
List<int> numeros = new List<int>() { 17, 19, 20, -11, -12, 11, -13, -15, -17 };
        var par = numeros.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList();
        var impar = numeros.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).ToList();
        if (par.Count < impar.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < par.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(par[i] + " Index: " + numeros.IndexOf(par[i]));
            }
        }
        else if (par.Count > impar.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < impar.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(impar[i] + " Index: " + numeros.IndexOf(impar[i]));
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
```